# Wortstellung im Satz - wo steht 'wieder' am besten?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure, word-order

Was klingt am besten?

> Ich freue mich immer darüber, wenn ich im Frühling den Vogel wieder singen höre.

oder

> Ich freue mich immer darüber, wenn ich im Frühling wieder den Vogel singen höre.

oder

> Ich freue mich immer wieder darüber, wenn ich im Frühling wieder den Vogel singen höre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alle Formulierungen sind richtig - die Unterschiede liegen in Nuancen und Details der Bedeutung:

> Ich freue mich immer darüber, wenn ich im Frühling den Vogel wieder singen höre

--> Du freust Dich, dass der Vogel wieder singt (Betonung auf 'singen'; das Singen ist der entscheidende Punkt)

> Ich freue mich immer darüber, wenn ich im Frühling wieder den Vogel singen höre

--> Du freust Dich, dass der Vogel wieder singt (Betonung auf Vogel. Wegen des Singulars könnte das auch einen speziellen Vogel oder eine Vogelart meinen, der bzw. die jedes Frühjahr zurückkehrt.)

> Ich freue mich immer wieder darüber, wenn ich im Frühling wieder den Vogel singen höre

--> Immer wieder, jedes einzelne Mal bin ich froh, wenn ich den Vogel im Frühjahr singen höre. Die Betonung liegt hier auf der wiederholten Freude, einen bzw. den Vogel im Frühjahr singen zu hören.

Aber, wie gesagt, die Unterschiede sind klein und in den Nuancen.

Comment: Wenn die Frage auf deutsch ist, darfst du gerne auch auf deutsch antworten (Nein: Du *sollst* sogar).

Comment: stimmt. War mir beim Schreiben nicht aufgefallen. Danke.